# Accessing Xcode documentation shows login window

Tags: xcode, api

I've had no trouble accessing the API documentation but now suddenly it shows a login window (see image). I tried login with Safari and then reopen the API documentation but it still shows the login window. And if I try to write my password it says the file is locked for editing.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of Xcode? I too had this problem a while back but I thought they fixed it in version 4.2.1 (Build 4D502).

From the 4.2.1 changelog:

> · Corrects an erroneous locked file dialog appearing in the
>   documentation window.

Comment: Actually I'm not. I'm using 5.0. I will try to see if upgrading will do the trick.

Comment: 5.0 is the iOS SDK version. In Xcode, go the the "Xcode" menu, and select "About Xcode". If the version is less than 4.2.1, go to the Mac App Store and update the software.

Comment: Yes of course :) Minor confusion there, I was running 4.2 so I will upgrade to 4.2.1.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem too in Xcode 4.2

Go to

```
Xcode > preferences > Downloads > Documentation
```

Select IOS 5.0 and IOS 4.2 and click install.

I think what's happening is XCode navigates to the online documentation since you don't have any local ones and then asks you to login but the documentation browser has the fetched file locked for editing. Downloading the docs locally worked for me.